# How to consume other GraphQL API from Apollo Server implementation?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have an Apollo Server implementation in which consume other REST APIs, I need to know, how can I use another GraphQL API inside a resolver?

I expect an Apollo Server implementation that works as an API Gateway to consume other APIs (REST or GraphQL)

Answer (score 0):

A GraphQL request is made like most other REST calls, with `POST` with `application/json` header.  It still hits an endpoint, passes data, and provides a body with the `query`.  You don't need a fancy client like `Apollo`, but you will need to know the implementation;

A `query` parameter also needs to be passed as a `string`.

Here is an example call using `axios` in javascript:

```
const data = await axios.post(GRAPHQL_URL, {
  query: `
    getUser(userID: 1234){
      id
      name
      age
    }
  `,
}, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```